# Heroku instances in an Amazon VPC - Possible?

Tags: heroku, amazon-web-services

My company uses AWS heavily and has several Amazon Direct Connect network links from our points of presence into Amazon. These reduce our latency and costs.

http://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/

We would like to be able to use Heroku more extensively with our internal applications, but the dynos would need to exist inside our Amazon VPCs in order for us to get the latency and cost benefits. I can't see a way to do this.

Is there any way for Heroku customers to run their dynos inside specific Amazon VPCs?